# make two similar javascript functions work together

Tags: javascript, html, function

I started with Javascript recently. I found a piece of code which changes the class of an object on scroll using pure javascript.
Here is that code -

```
window.onscroll = function() {
  if (window.scrollY > 1) {
    document.getElementById('nav2').className = "after";
  } else {
      document.getElementById('nav2').className = "before";
  }};
window.onscroll = function() {
  if (window.scrollY > 1) {
    document.getElementById('list').className = "ul2";
  } else {
      document.getElementById('list').className = "ul";
  }};
```

The problem is that in this code only the second function runs , the first one does not run until i remove the second function. 
Please suggest any pure javascript method to solve this issue

Comment: Just put the code from one function to another

Answer (score 3):

Problem is because when you are saying second time `window.onscroll=somefun` it's overwriting the existing one. So now only it will call the second function `onscroll`.

Just write every thing in one function like bellow

```
window.onscroll = function() {
  if (window.scrollY > 1) {
    document.getElementById('nav2').className = "after";
    document.getElementById('list').className = "ul2";
  } else {
      document.getElementById('nav2').className = "before";
      document.getElementById('list').className = "ul";
  }};
```

Comment: sometimes, you can't do that, the event listener approach is better, IMHO

Comment: @amenthes might be but here it should work, I told what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

If you assign it like this (`window.onscroll = ...`) then you can only ever have one function in there (the next would overwrite the first).

The better way would be to add an [event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener).

in your case that might be

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function (event) {
    //...
}, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  window.onscroll = function() {
  if (window.scrollY > 1) {
    document.getElementById('nav2').className = "after";
    document.getElementById('list').className = "ul2";
  } else {
      document.getElementById('nav2').className = "before";
      document.getElementById('list').className = "ul";
  }};
```

U can use code like this..

Answer (score 0):

The better solution for this `addEventListener()` - [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener), don't assign event listeners to window's property directly.

So do it like this:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', yourFunction, false);
```